# Matlab painters fails to work unless figure is moved on screen

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

While trying to set the `renderer` to `painters` in Matlab, I have encountered a particularly strange behavior. After plotting a figure, the command `set(gcf,'renderer','painters')` only executes properly if the figure is first moved on the screen from its initial position. If the figure is not moved before executing said command, the following error message is printed to the command window:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a container to a container on a different GraphicsDevice
at java.awt.Component.checkGD(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
at com.mathworks.hg.peer.FigurePanel.assembleFigurePanel(FigurePanel.java:218)
at com.mathworks.hg.peer.FigurePanel.reconstructFigurePanel(FigurePanel.java:143)
at com.mathworks.hg.peer.FigurePanel.handleNotification(FigurePanel.java:88)
at com.mathworks.hg.peer.FigureNotificationHandlerImpl.forwardNotification(FigureNotificationHandlerImpl.java:62)
at com.mathworks.hg.peer.FigureNotificationHandlerImpl.handleNotification(FigureNotificationHandlerImpl.java:29)
at com.mathworks.hg.peer.FigureAxisComponentProxy.construct(FigureAxisComponentProxy.java:89)
at com.mathworks.hg.peer.FigureAxisComponentProxy.setVisual(FigureAxisComponentProxy.java:112)
at com.mathworks.hg.peer.FigureHG1Mediator.setClientVisual(FigureHG1Mediator.java:135)
at com.mathworks.hg.peer.FigurePeer.doSetVisual(FigurePeer.java:2418)
at com.mathworks.hg.peer.FigurePeer.access$1100(FigurePeer.java:119)
at com.mathworks.hg.peer.FigurePeer$25.run(FigurePeer.java:2430)
at com.mathworks.hg.util.HGPeerQueue$HGPeerRunnablesRunner.runit(HGPeerQueue.java:228)
at com.mathworks.hg.util.HGPeerQueue$HGPeerRunnablesRunner.runNotThese(HGPeerQueue.java:260)
at com.mathworks.hg.util.HGPeerQueue$HGPeerRunnablesRunner.run(HGPeerQueue.java:276)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

If I were only printing a single figure, I wouldn't mind acquiescing to this idiosyncrasy of Matlab, but I would like to generate plots and save eps/pdf output thereof iteratively via a loop statement. How can this peculiar requirement be avoided?

I have constructed a minimal working example which may aid in diagnosing the problem.

```
x=1:10;
y1=1:10;
y2=11:20;
ax1=axes;
[ax,Y1,Y2]=plotyy(x,y1',x,y2',@bar,@bar);
patchY2 = get(Y2,'children');
set(patchY2,'FaceAlpha',0.65);
ax2=axes('Position',[0 -10 1 1]);
linkaxes([ax ax2],'x');
rgb2cm
set(gcf,'renderer','painters');
```

Note that [`rgb2cm`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35469-rgb2cm-fix-rgb-color-data-in-painters-mode/content/rgb2cm.m) is a submission to the MATLAB File Exchange. It acts to replace patch rgb colors with `colormap`-indexed colors so that the `renderer` can be set to `painters`.

**Edit:** The problem occurs using MATLAB 7.11.0 (R2010b) on a Debian 7 machine with the 3.2.0-4-amd64 kernel.

Comment: How about setting the position of the figure programmatically?

Comment: I got the same error with some other code using matlab in an ubuntu multi screen environment. Using only one monitor might fixed it for me.

Comment: Version and OS would be helpful information. I can not replicate this in R2013b and OS X. Does calling `drawnow`, or even just `drawnow('expose')`, help?

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions. @chappjc: I tried setting the position programmatically, but the error still occurs. @Daniel: I was using a multi-screen environment in Debian, but switching to only one monitor did not work in my case. @horchler: I have added version and OS information to the post. I tried calling `drawnow`, `drawnow expose`, and `drawnow expose update` just before the call to set the renderer, but issuing these commands had no effect.

Comment: For what it's worth, make sure your distribution is up-to-date, including graphics drivers if possible. Alternatively, if this used to not be a problem, maybe there was a regression in a recent update. :S Sorry that I can't be more helpful.

Comment: @SchighSchagh: Thanks for the suggestion. My system is as up-to-date as possible without going to backports or Debian 8 (testing).

Answer (score 0):

Open and move the figure first, then reuse the same figure for each plot in your loop, using `clf` to clear the figure after saving.